# Which error families are allowed in generalized least squares models?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, generalized-least-squares

Which error families are allowed in generalized least squares (gls) models? Can I have, for example, a binomial glm and define a covariance structure (which, I guess, makes it a gls) in it (see below example)?

```
model <- glmmTMB(response ~ predictor + ar1(time + 0 | group), data = data, family = binomial(link = logit))
```

And also, should I call a glm with a covariance structure a gls?

Comment: When you fit a logistic regression, your loss function is not square loss but cross-entropy loss, so “least squares” is no longer in the mix; no, it is not generalized least squares.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Does my formula make sense by the way? Can I call it a binomial glm (or logistic regression) with AR(1) covar structure?

Comment: I don’t see how you’re doing an autoregressive error term.

Comment: I see where you’re trying to introduce an autoregressive element, but you’re using it as a predictor. Predictors aren’t error. Error is what’s still unaccounted for after you use the predictors, so I don’t think you’re doing what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks. But then how can I introduce an AR(1) covariance structure to this model using glmmTMB? Assuming time here is a factor with unit differences between levels (e.g. 1991, 1992, 1993, ...) and that the AR(1) covariance structure is the right one to deifne.

Comment: You could try using the [GEE](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtgee.pdf) approach if your time series is short, although it is answering a different question. In short, GEE consider "population average" log odds ratios rather than the individual odds ratio